# SQL Server 2008 subquery using NOT IN

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

stuck on a problem, can't seem to code the query correctly, help please

here's the question

> Write a SELECT statement that returns the name, city, and state of each vendor that's located in a unique city and state. In other words, don't include vendors that have a city and state in common with another vendor.
>
> Sort the result set by VendorState, VendorCity
>
> Use NOT IN subquery.  The expression VendorState + VendorCity should be used in WHERE, (subquery SELECT, GROUP BY) clauses.  The HAVING clause controls the results of duplicate city+state.  Execute the subquery from the basic, and add one clause each time to compare the results.

- Outer query – display all vendors NOT IN
- Inner query - duplicate city+state vendors

  Table:
  Vendors
  Columns:
  VendorName,VendorState,VendorCity

Comment: Why use NOT IN? I wouldn't...

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

Well the inner query must return a combined string of city and state (really stupid way of doing it)
so that would be

```
SELECT VendorCity + VendorState
FROM   Vendors
GROUP BY VendorCity, VendorState
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And the outer query simply needs to say where it's not in the list.

```
Select *
FROM Venders
WHERE VendorCity + VendorState
     NOT IN 
   (SELECT VendorCity + VendorState
    FROM   Vendors
    GROUP BY VendorCity, VendorState
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
ORDER BY VendorState, VendorCity
```

Comment: thank you so much, can't believe i couldn't come up with this, must of been overthinking it

Comment: I forgot the order by, added it now.